# Showing that the system $x^4+y^4+z^4=1$, $x^2+y^2+2z^2=\sqrt 7$ has no real solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

> Show that the system of equations 
>   $$\begin{cases}
> x^4+y^4+\phantom{2}z^4=1\\
> x^2+y^2+2z^2=\sqrt 7 \\
> \end{cases}$$ has no real solutions.

At a first glance I thought about Newton sums, but the second equation is not that great, maybe if we had $z^2$ instead of $2z^2$. Then I though about somehow using some clever inequalities, but I wasn't successful.

Comment: "clever inequalities" is right. Apply Cauchy-Schwarz to get $x^2+y^2+2z^2\le\dots<\sqrt 7$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Oh, yes, that is correct. I underestimated the problem and that's why I didn't think of CS.

Answer (score 7):

Write $a=x^2,b=y^2,c=z^2$ so we have
$$a^2+b^2+c^2=1\qquad a+b+2c=\sqrt7$$
The first equation is the unit sphere and the second is a plane; a real solution corresponds to an intersection, where the origin-plane distance is $1$. But the shortest distance from $a+b+2c=\sqrt7$ to the origin is $\sqrt{\frac76}>1$. Thus the plane does not intersect the sphere and the system in $a,b,c$ has no real solution, implying that the original system also has no real solutions.

Comment: Very nice geometrical interpretation, I hadn't thought about that.